# Removing text from existing product description

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am am using code to create a line break in a product description, and this works fine.

But now I also need correct code for removing anything that comes after "1" in the description. Can anyone help with this please?

```js
$('#description').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.substr(0, h.indexOf('1') + 1);
});

$('#description').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.substr(0, h.indexOf('2') + 2);
});

$('#description').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.substr(0, h.indexOf('3') + 3);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="description">party hat 1 for men</div>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the input you have and the output you expect to generate.

Comment: Can you give an example for this?

Comment: say i have a product description "party hat 1 for men" and I want it to become "party hat 1"

Comment: `h.substr(0, h.indexOf('1'))` See the duplicate I marked for more info

Comment: thanks all! @Rory, this nearly does the trick but removes the 1 as well. The 1 should stay.

Comment: `h.substr(0, h.indexOf('1') + 1)`

Comment: What am I doing wrong @Rory? Could you please check the snippet added to my question? It"s giving an error and it's not performing the function I need it to.

Comment: Your snippet didn't include jQuery. I added it for you, now it works fine

Comment: Oops. Thanks for helping me, the dummy!

Comment: Please, one more thing @Rory. In my questionI have edited my snippet, copying more of the same code. But this cancels proper functionality. Could you have one last look please.

Comment: You need to amend the code for cases where the character you're looking for doesn't exist: `return h.indexOf('2') != -1 ? h.substr(0, h.indexOf('2') + 2) : h;`

Comment: Great!! @Rory, yes it works!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#description').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.split('1')[0] + 1;
})
```

Comment: Edited the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5xbfhh7b/)

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var str = "party hat 1 for men";

    alert(str.substr(0, str.indexOf('1')+1));
});
```